# Proper way to initialize this attributes in JS object

Tags: javascript, class, object, optimization

Is there any way I can make this code:

```
function person(first, last, age, eye) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyeColor = eye;
}
```

To look something similar to this:

```
function person(first, last, age, eye) {
    this = {
        firstName: first,
        lastName: last,
        age: age,
        eyeColor: eye
    }
}
```

With many variables to initialize first method looks stupid to programmer, who wants to optimize everything.

Comment: `Object.assign(this,{
        firstName: first,
        lastName: last,
        age: age,
        eyeColor: eye
    })`

Comment: The first method doesn’t look stupid to me. It’s straightforward and easy to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)** method to copy object properties to target object.

```
function person(first, last, age, eye) {
    Object.assign(this, {
        firstName: first,
        lastName: last,
        age: age,
        eyeColor: eye
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides Object.assign() mentioned by Pranav. You can also try to pass an option object to the constructor.

E.g.,

```
function person(option) {
    this.option = option;
}

// usage
var person1 = new person({
    firstName: first,
    lastName: last,
    age: age,
    eyeColor: eye
});
```